# What is the mime type of jsonl files?

Tags: json, mime-types

When responding to a `http` request for a file of type `jsonl`, i.e., a collection of json object separated by new lines, what mime type should I set? I tried searching for `jsonl mime type` and `jsonl mimetype` on SO, but could not find anything about it.

My response is as follows (flask/python):

```
response = Response(
    generate_jsonl(object_iterable),
    mimetype='application/json',
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=%s.json' % file_name,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some web sites use `application/json-lines`.

Some `application/jsonl`.

And some even more exotic, like `application/x-...`.

It seems to be a take-your-pick territory...

Comment: `application/jsonl+json` <-- the [json suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Suffix) is technically a lie, but it encourages Chrome to display the file as text/plain. Otherwise it downloads as octet/stream.

Comment: `text/jsonl` is [used by Shopify](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/imports)